# Find box contour using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I need to find the contour of boxes and of the hot stuff in the box coming from an IR camera. I can easily find the contour of the hot stuff inside the box using a treshold multiotsu with classes=2, but I cannot manage to reliably get to the contour of the box. I tried with using Canny and some dilation, but the results are not exactly satisfactory.

Is there a robust way of finding square edges in an image like this?
NOTE: The level of brightness vary from image to image, but the box is always way colder than the stuff inside
NOTE2: The image is 3 channels even if it's an IR image
NOTE3: The expected box is the ideal box that I'd want, but anything close even if it doesn't get the slanted side would still work

```
def is_square(cnt, eps=0.05, aspect_ratio_range=(0.9, 1.1)):
    # Approximate the contour to reduce the number of points
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, eps * peri, True)
    
    # The contour is considered a square if it has 4 vertices and is convex
    if len(approx) == 4 and cv2.isContourConvex(approx):
        _, _, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        aspect_ratio = w / float(h)
        return aspect_ratio_range[0] <= aspect_ratio <= aspect_ratio_range[1]
    return False
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred_cp, 134,0, apertureSize=3)

vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 3))
dilated_vertical = cv2.dilate(edges, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)

horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 1))
dilated = cv2.dilate(edges, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
square_contours=[cnt for cnt in contours if is_square(cnt,0.05)]

cnt=square_cnt[1] #Here I tried every possible contour that i find
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(max_cnt)
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)  # Draw rectangle

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

original image file:
[image: Original image file]

Contours that I find:

[image: contours that I find]

Contours I can get with Canny:

[image: contours I can get with Canny]

Expected Bounding box:
[image: Expected bounding box]

EDIT: Tweaking around with the histograms of the blue channel of the image i managed to come up with an algorithm that kinda manages to identify the top and bottom of the box (that's the side that I need the most) as long as the relative brightness of the image respects certain conditions. Unfortunately when it gets out of this parameters the algo doesn't work. I am in need of some more robust method to get the box boundaries.

```
    r,g,b= cv2.split(im)
    b=cv2.bitwise_not(b)
    h=cv2.calcHist([b],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
    h=h[15:]
    # Calculate the indices of the maxima of the histogram
    indices = argrelextrema(h, np.greater)
    # Get the values of the maxima of the histogram
    maxima = h[indices]

    # Find the indices of the 2 highest maxima
    top_2_indices = maxima.argsort()[-2:][::-1]

    # These are the VALUES of h at indices
    maxima = h[indices]
    # These are the indices of the highest values in the maxima array
    top_2_indices = maxima.argsort()[-2:][::-1]

    # These are the indices in h of the two highest peaks just found
    highest_values = indices[0][top_2_indices]
    # These are the same values, still in h, but sorted in ascending order, so the left peak appears first, and then the right peak.
    highest_values_sorted=sorted(highest_values)

    values_h_at_peaks= h[highest_values_sorted]
    small_peak_value=min(values_h_at_peaks)[0]
    
    _, tresh = cv2.threshold(b, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU) # thresholding
    tresh_padded = np.pad(tresh, ((0, 2), (0, 0)), 'constant')

    row_sums = np.sum(tresh_padded, axis=1)
    window_size = 3
    window_sums = np.convolve(row_sums, np.ones(window_size), 'valid')

    peaks, properties = find_peaks(window_sums, height=small_peak_value/2,distance=30,prominence=0.5)
    peak_heights = properties['peak_heights']

    top_2_indices = peak_heights.argsort()[-2:][::-1]

    # Get the 3 best peaks
    best_peaks = peaks[top_2_indices]

    cv2.line(im, (0, best_peaks[1]), (im.shape[1], best_peaks[1]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.line(im, (0, best_peaks[0]), (im.shape[1], best_peaks[0]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

I attach some more image for whoever wants to try:
The first 2 images can be classified correctly, the last 2 are examples that unfortunately don't work due to their brightness

[image: can identify correctly]
[image: also identifies correctly]
[image: can't identify]
[image: also can't identify]

Comment: Can you provide an image with the expected bounding box, please?

Comment: Thank you Corralien, I uploaded the rough bounding box that I'd want.  I realize that because of the angle of the camera the box is not a perfect square (top side is slighlt slanted), on how this fact reflects on the problem.

Comment: please add the image itself for us to be able to reproduce your problem. Also, your expected bounding "box" actually looks like a trapezoid, there would be no way to actually do this with the bounding rect method.

Comment: your plots are illustrations. an [mre] should include the data itself.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize the axis were in the image, added the original image file itself. @TinoD Yes I'm aware that it it looks like a trapezoid, in case it's too difficult the closest square box to that trapezoid, or the position of the corners of that trapezoid would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I did some thresholding on the red channel and the contour was very easy to find, here's the code:

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("heat.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
redChannel = im[:,:,0] # get red channel
redChannel[redChannel < 200] = 0 # remove weak values
_, thresholdedImage = cv2.threshold(redChannel, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU) # thresholding
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholdedImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # get contours
largestContour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea) # get largest contour
imContoured = cv2.drawContours(im.copy(), largestContour, -1, (0,0,0), 3) # draw contour for illustration
minAreaRect = cv2.minAreaRect(largestContour) # generate minAreaRect object
box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(minAreaRect)) # get the box from the minAreaRectangle
imContoured = cv2.drawContours(imContoured, [box], 0, (0, 255, 255), 2)  # draw minimum rect
```

Now here is the thing, there is some "cheating", in the sense that I used a fixed threshold. In any case, this is how the result looked like:

[image: With contour and bounding rect]

In case you get some weird results, try to play around with the threshold. Going higher might be even better, however I only have this example so I can't know for sure.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help Tino, unfortunately a fixed treshold won't do, I updated the main thread to share some more examples that will make that clear. I had more luck working on the blue channel of the image, as the sides are a usually colder, but unfortunately this being an IR image ,some other times the sides tend to "fade" in the background if the temperature of the top is too high.   
I thought there was gonna be some easy method to find geometrical contours in an image, but it seems I was very mistaken >.<

Comment: I tried some stuff and it seems the one picture that is really not working is the very cold one (last image). And that one is especially weird since the background is hot too. I try at it again, that last image will be tricky